# MacBook Pro / OS X Lion

Tags: macbook-pro

5 years ago broke my laptop, finally got it repaired but, forgot all my passwords ! Tried to do a factory reset however, the macintosh hd is locked and I can’t find a way to unlock it.
Anyone can help ?

Comment: When you say "the macintosh HD is locked", at what point are you presented with a prompt for a password? Are you prompted for a username as well?

Comment: Yes I am, I tried with iCloud account but it says I’m connected to internet (which isn’t the case)

Comment: This is an older laptop from before Apple started locking things really down.  Can you boot on the original install media?

Comment: Just managed to erase the disk But it takes 8h so I’ll see

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, if there was a well-known way around passwords that you could just apply, then there would be little point in having them.

There are several different types of password:

**Firmware Password**
If you see a prompt almost immediately, then that's likely to be a firmware password.

**User prompt**
Normally, the OS loads and then asks for a username and password.

**FileVault password**
Sometimes, the OS asks for a password in order to access the encrypted disk.

There is also your AppleID name and password.

It sounds like you're talking about a disk encrypted with FileVault.

Most of these will involve contacting Apple to sort out. You will need proof of your ownership.

Do you have a backup that isn't encrypted? If so, then you can wipe the disk and restore the backup. That will work for a FileVault protected disk.

Comment: When I turn the laptop on it goes on normal with my old admin account (which i can’t remember the password) - i tried using my Apple ID and it says that I’m not connected to internet (which isn’t true) - I did the internet recovery and on FileVault there’s nothing, I can’t install OS X LION because I don’t know the Macintosh HD password I don’t mind setting it back to factory because clearly I don’t have any important folders but as I don’t have the Macintosh hd password I can’t .. Sorry I’m not that good in computers

Comment: If you boot to Recovery (Command R at boot), then you should be able to erase the disk and install MacOS again without any password for the disk getting in your way.